# replace or remove new line "\n" character from Spark dataset column value

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have below code to read xml

```
Dataset<Row> dataset1 = SparkConfigXMLProcessor.sparkSession.read().format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
                .option("rowTag", properties.get(EventHubConsumerConstants.IG_ORDER_TAG).toString())
                .load(properties.get("C:\\inputOrders.xml").toString());
```

one of the column value getting new line character.
i want to replace it with some character or just want to remove it.
Please help

Answer (score 8):

```
dataset1.withColumn("menuitemname_clean", regexp_replace(col("menuitemname"), "[\n\r]", " "))
```

Above code will work

Answer (score 3):

This is what I used. I usually add a tab (\t), too. Having both \r and \n will find UNIX (\n), Windows (\r), and OSX (\r) newlines.

```
Dataset<Row> newDF = dataset1.withColumn("menuitemname", regexp_replace(col("menuitemname"), "\n|\r", ""));
```

Answer (score -3):

Below code resolve my issue

```
Dataset<Row> newDF = dataset1.withColumn("menuitemname", regexp_replace(col("menuitemname"), "[\\n]", ""));
```